# HTTParty integer in request headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty, net-http

I need to POST to an API, which requires a header in the request called `"Timestamp"`, whose value has to be an integer (current time from epoch as an integer).

I tried to do this with `HTTParty` and with `Net::HTTP` as follows:

```
response = HTTParty.post(route, body: options[:body].to_json,headers: { 'Timestamp' => Time.now.to_i, 'Authorization' => "Bearer #{options[:token]}",'Content-Type' => 'application/json' })
# >> NoMethodError: undefined method `strip' for 1522273989:Integer
```

It calls `strip` on the header value, which throws an error because you can't call `strip` on an integer.

Does anyone have any idea how I can pass an integer in the request headers?

Comment: could you give a more complete stack trace? It is hard to deduce much from just the error line.

Comment: Your problem is merely syntactical. `Time.now.to_i.to_s` will do the trick.

Comment: @Sean there's nothing else to the stack trace. It's not my API so I don't see what's happening on the other end all I get back is #<NoMethodError: undefined method `strip' for 1522274875:Integer>

Comment: @JoshBrody I tried .to_s but unfortunately no luck. If do that they hit me back with an error saying "Replay attack detected" it has to be an integer not a string

Comment: You can't send an integer in a header. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `.to_s` on the integer:

```
response = HTTParty.post(route, body: options[:body].to_json,headers: { 'Timestamp' => Time.now.to_i.to_s, 'Authorization' => "Bearer #{options[:token]}",'Content-Type' => 'application/json' })
```

You can't really send an integer in a header - its the server on the receiving end that must convert the plaintext headers from the request.

> Header fields are colon-separated name-value pairs in clear-text
>   string format, terminated by a carriage return (CR) and line feed (LF)
>   character sequence.
>   [List of HTTP header fields - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#General_format)

Comment: I tried .to_s but unfortunately no luck. If do that they hit me back with an error saying "Replay attack detected" it has to be an integer not a string

It's good to know it's not just me that it seemed weird to. I'll have to reach out to the API developer and see if they can change it or handle the conversion on their end

Comment: They have to handle conversion on their end - HTTP headers are defined by the IETF as a plaintext format. Its just not possible to do it any other way. You can't put a poodle in a fax machine and expect to get anything else than a piece of paper out in the other end.

Comment: haha thanks I asked them about it. I'll accept the answer because there's no other way around it.